# How to play rtsp url in browser using angular6?

Tags: stream, angular6, rtsp

In my app, I have to play `N` number of videos on browsers. In addition, I had only `rtsp` URL with it's `username` and `password`.

I had done some RND on that and I found that there are some `media` services and `npm package` are available like `Wowza` and `ffmpeg` respectively.

In my case, I haven't any backend services. Is there any way to stream live camera feed on browsers. I'm using `Angular6`.

I have a URL of the stream like this.

```
rtsp://name:password@yourip:port/webcam/xyz?channel=10&subtype=25
```

Can anyone suggest or share any reference link which can help me?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 browsers can play live video as HLS. 
So you need a streaming server to input your RTSP stream and output a HLS stream.

Implementation:

- For RTSP to HLS, Wowza SE can be used to input RTSP and re-stream as RTMP or directly HTML5 HLS to web pages. This involves having a dedicated server to deploy streaming services and licensing the Wowza SE:
  https://www.wowza.com/pricing/streaming-engine
- Another option is to get a turnkey plan (lower costs and avoid server installation/administration hassle):
  https://webrtchost.com

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I want to convert my RTSP to HLS from angular6.
Can I integrate the Wowza server in my angular app so that it can give me translated URL?
 As I get RTSP URL in API response.